# Replot multiple jqPlot on tab activate

Tags: jquery, tabs, jqplot

I have a dynamic page with tabs, I am currently adding 2 jqPlot items to the page, but this might not always be the case. It could be one, three, four or more...

jqPlot does not render immediately if the tab is not active. The samples say to get around this... run the tab activate...

```
    $('#tabs').tabs({ activate : function(event, ui) {
        plot47.replot();
    }});
```

This works fine, if there is only one chart on the page.

If two charts are on the page, then running 2 lots of activate only runs the last one. The first one is ignored.

Unfotunately, I cannot know how many charts there are when the page is created, which means I can't put all the replot() calls in the one activate.

So, how do I add my multiple plots into the one activate, or how do I run multiple activate's?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha, worked out a way to do it... may not be the prettiest, but the test I have done on jsfiddle seems to work...

```
var fns = [];

$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        var active = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
        $("#tabid").html('the tab id is ' + $("#tabs ul>li a").eq(active).attr("href"));

        for (i = 0; i < fns.length; i++)
        {
            eval(fns[i]);
        }
    }
}

);

function first()
{
    alert('1');
}

function second()
{
    alert('2');
}

fns.push("first()");
fns.push("second()");
```

I'm still new to javascript, but at least this helps me around my problem. I will create the function in each graph, then push the function name into the array, then eval the function name. The function will simply call replot()